# Matching ranked or similar opponent

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

Is it possible in iOS Game Center to match an opponent with similar skills or ranking? I want to match an opponent with some ranged value such as experience or total score. I'm new with iOS matchmaking system. Thanks for any advice.

I did some research and found playerGroup and playerAttribute properties for match requests. Can these properties be helpful to me for what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GKMatchRequest`'s `playerGroup` property is exactly what you are looking for. It's an unsigned 32-bit integer that you can set to player level *(or a range of levels like 1-5, 6-10 etc. to increase number of potential players to match)* for example and you will only get back a `GKMatch` with two players of that level *(or level range)*.

More info: [Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) / [Player Groups](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW10)